# Form Field Data to span/div

Tags: forms, copy, concatenation

I am wanting to concatenate a few form fields into a span or div area.
I have found a script on the web that works really well for me. But it concatenates the fields into another form field.

What do I need to change to tell it to put it in a span/div.

I have made a fiddle to help explain what Im after.
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZHfB/

Cheers in advance!!

Comment: "But it concatenates the fields into another form field." What does this mean?

Comment: u want to have in <span> or <div> not in input field? ie show Full name in <div>Mr John </div> sth like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle updated with answer, [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZHfB/2/).

1) Replace *copyPassDetails textbox* with a span/div:

```
    <div class="field">
        <label for="copyPassDetails">Full Name:</label>
        <span id="fullName"></span>
    </div>
```

2) Replace *textbox' val() inside bind function* with *span's html()*:

```
$('#fullName').html($('#Title').val() + ' ' +
                         $('#First_Name').val() + ' ' +
                         $('#Last_Name').val() );
```

Comment: How would I go about instead of onblur of a field, but onclick of a button (eg. filling out fields, then clicking on a submit button to concatenate the data)

Comment: Just to concatenate ? To post the full name with form, you can add a hidden field in form and set its value on button click before submitting the form: `$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ var fullName = $('#Title').val() + ' ' + $('#First_Name').val() + ' ' + $('#Last_Name').val(); // To post the full name with form $('#hdnFullName').val(fullName); $('form').submit(); });`

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. Are you able to have a look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UUYCC/  Sorry I'm still new to js.   But your feedback is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Read the comments inside javascript window of fiddle carefully, it does what you want. [http://jsfiddle.net/UUYCC/4/]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Coder. Your comments also help me to understand how it works. :)

Comment: One last question regarding this, I have a select menu with dynamically generated values and text. How can I use your code to just display the visible selected text in the menu. I dont want to use the value. http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/vau3y/   People on the net say to add 'option:selected'  but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `var strName = $('#Pickup_airport :selected').text();` to get the visible selected text and `$('#fullPickup').html(strName);` to display it. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vau3y/1/

Comment: Coder, I'm trying to use your examples above to make it work another way. Could you possibly help me with the syntax of this.  http://jsfiddle.net/UUYCC/5/   I've commented out what I've put in there of what I want it to do. All I want is it to display the numbers, but if the option 'more' is selected, then put in the span '5 or more'

Comment: See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UUYCC/6/ and read the comments I wrote there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="post" action="">


        <div class="field">
            <label for="Title">Title:</label>
            <select name="Title" id="Title">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                            <option value="Revd">Revd</option>
                            <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
                            <option value="Judge">Judge</option>
                        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="First_Name"> First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="First_Name" name="First_Name" />
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="Last_Name"> Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name" />
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="copyPassDetails">Full Name:</label>
           <!-- <input type="text" id="copyPassDetails" name="address" /> -->
<div id="copyPassDetails"></div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <script>
    $('#Title, #First_Name, #Last_Name').bind('blur', function() {

        $('#copyPassDetails').html($('#Title').val() + ' ' +
                                 $('#First_Name').val() + ' ' +
                                 $('#Last_Name').val() );
    });
    </script>
```

> Try this, i have edited 
>   **`<input type="text" id="copyPassDetails" name="address" />`**  this to 
>   **`<div id="copyPassDetails"></div>`**  and   **$('#copyPassDetails').val(** to **$('#copyPassDetails').html(**
>
> To put the value in `<div><span>` tags you need to use html and for
>   input val